# Find all solutions of $\frac{2}{x}+\frac{8}{y}=\frac13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ where $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ Find all possible solutions to the diophantine equation $$\frac{2}{x}+\frac{8}{y}=\frac13$$

---

I tried with $AM\ge GM$ and I got
$$xy\ge576$$
Then I used the fact,
$$\frac{2}{x}<\frac{1}{3}\:\:\textrm{and}\:\:\frac{8}{y}<\frac{1}{3}$$ and I got these two results $$x>6,y>24$$ but what to do next$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint. $$y=\frac {24x}{x-6}=\frac {24(x-6)+24\cdot6}{x-6}=24+\frac {24\cdot 6}{x-6}$$

Comment: Hint: $xy-6x-24x=0$ and $(x-6)(y-24)=144$

Comment: See the linked dupe (and its many linked questions) for the standard method(s) for solivng such equations (including those above).